# Pandas dataframe drop rows which store certain number of zeros in it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have dataframe which is having [13171 rows x 511 columns] what I wanted is remove the rows which is having certain number of zeros

for example

```
col0   col1  col2  col3   col4 col5
 ID1    0      2     0     2    0
 ID2    1      1     2     10   1
 ID3    0      1     3     4    0
 ID4    0      0     1     0    3
 ID5    0      0     0     0    1
```

in ID5 row contains 4 zeros in it so I wanted to drop that row. like this I have large dataframe which is having more than 100-300 zeros in rows
I tried below code

df=df[(df == 0).sum(1) >= 4]

for small dataset like above example code is working but for [13171 rows x 511 columns] not working(df=df[(df == 0).sum(1) >= 15]) any one suggest me how can I get proper result

output

```
 col0   col1  col2  col3   col4 col5
  ID1    0      2     0     2    0
  ID2    1      1     2     10   1
  ID3    0      1     3     4    0
  ID4    0      0     1     0    3
```

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for providing example data and showing what you have tried. Can you please post the error message and complete traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
drop_indexs = []
for i in range(len(df.iloc[:,0])):
    if (df.iloc[i,:]==0).sum()>=4:    # 4 is how many zeros should row min have
        drop_indexs.append(i)
updated_df = df.drop(drop_indexs)
```